# ggplot 2 - Race track plot error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to reproduce the Race track plot from ggplot2 (http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/coord_polar.html) on my own data.

```
> y[1:10,]
         cd cnt day year
1  2003-10-18   3 291 2003
2  2003-10-20   1 293 2003
3  2003-10-21   1 294 2003
4  2003-10-22   1 295 2003
5  2003-10-23   2 296 2003
6  2003-11-03   1 307 2003
7  2003-11-18   3 322 2003
8  2003-11-20   2 324 2003
9  2003-11-21   6 325 2003
10 2003-11-24   1 328 2003
> q <- ggplot(y, aes(y$day, y$year, fill=y$cnt)) + geom_bar(width = 0.9, position = "fill") + coord_polar(theta="x")
> q
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
In addition: Warning message:
In cbind(is.na(mmm), is.na(each)) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
```

But I am getting this error and I can not find any work around. Where does the 'origin' come in? Could anyone give me a hand on this? Thanks folks.

And here goes the output of str(y):

```
'data.frame':   2430 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ cd  :Class 'Date'  num [1:2430] 12343 12345 12346 12347 12348 ...
 $ cnt : int  3 1 1 1 2 1 3 2 6 1 ...
 $ day : num  291 293 294 295 296 307 322 324 325 328 ...
 $ year: num  2003 2003 2003 2003 2003 ...
```

Comment: Your error is not reproducible.  Although your code is slightly clumsy, it works fine on my machine without error.  I suggest you post the results of `str(y)` in your question, so we can see what your data looks like.

Comment: Or better yet `dput(y)` so we can re-create.

Comment: OK, `str(y)` doesn't give any clues.  What is the result of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: @gsk3  The thing is the data worked with geom_point() but they fail with geom_bar().

Comment: @Andrie 

R version 2.11.1 (2010-05-31) 
x86_64-pc-mingw32 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Czech_Czech Republic.1250  LC_CTYPE=Czech_Czech Republic.1250    LC_MONETARY=Czech_Czech Republic.1250
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          LC_TIME=Czech_Czech Republic.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  grid      methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.8.8 reshape_0.8.3 plyr_1.2.1    proto_0.3-8  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.4.2 tools_2.11.1

Answer (score 0):

As Andrie mentioned, your error isn't reproducible; that is, given the 10 sample data points, it seems to run fine on everyone else's machine.  I can reproduce it if I use slightly different code, as follows.

```
y <- read.table(tc <- textConnection("
cd cnt day year
2003-10-18   3 291 2003
2003-10-20   1 293 2003
2003-10-21   1 294 2003
2003-10-22   1 295 2003
2003-10-23   2 296 2003
2003-11-03   1 307 2003
2003-11-18   3 322 2003
2003-11-20   2 324 2003
2003-11-21   6 325 2003
2003-11-24   1 328 2003"), header = TRUE); close(tc)
y$cd <- as.Date(y$cd, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

q <- ggplot(y, aes(y$day, y$cd, fill=y$cnt)) + geom_bar(width = 0.9, position = "fill") + coord_polar(theta="x")
q
```

Did you actually include `cd` as an aesthetic in your plot?

---

A couple of minor style points:

You don't need to declare `y$` for each of the variable names in the `aes()` call.  `ggplot` is smart enough to look inside the data frame you provided in the first argument.

Best not call your variable `q`, since that is a function name already.

Comment: No have not used cd as aesthethic. I was using day as x and year as y variable the whole time. So doesnt anyone know where the Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied comes from? What is the origin?